# Proof by Induction: Alternating Sum of Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, fibonacci-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show that $f_0 - f_1 + f_2 - \cdots - f_{2n-1} + f_{2n} = f_{2n-1} - 1$ when $n$ is a positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82140/show-that-f-0-f-1-f-2-cdots-f-2n-1-f-2n-f-2n-1-1-when-n)

This is a homework question so I'm looking to just be nudged in the right direction, I'm not asking for my work to be done for me.

---

The Fibonacci numbers are defined as follows: $f_0 = 0$, $f_1 = 1$, and $f_{n+2} = f_n + f_{n+1}$ whenever $n \geq 0$. Prove that when $n$ is a positive integer:

\begin{equation*}
f_0 - f_1 + f_2 + \ldots - f_{2n-1} + f_{2n} = f_{2n-1} - 1
\end{equation*}

---

So as I understand it, this is an induction problem. I've done the basis step using $n = 1$:

\begin{align*}
- f_{2(1)-1} + f_{2(1)} &= f_{2(1)-1} - 1\newline
- f_1 + f_2 &= f_1 - 1\newline
- 1 + 1 &= 1 - 1\newline
0 &= 0
\end{align*}

I've concluded that the inductive hypothesis is that $- f_{2n-1} + f_{2n} = f_{2n-1} - 1$ is true for some $n \geq 1$. From what I can gather, the inductive step is:

\begin{equation*}
f_0 - f_1 + f_2 + \ldots - f_{2n-1} + f_{2n} - f_{2n+1} = f_{2n} - 1
\end{equation*}

However, what I find when I try to prove it using that equation is that it is incorrect. For example, when I take $n = 1$

\begin{align*}
- f_{2(1)-1} + f_{2(1)} + f_{2(1)+1} &\neq f_{2(1)} - 1\newline
- f_1 + f_2 - f_3 &\neq f_2 - 1\newline
- 1 + 1 - 2 &\neq 1 - 1\newline
-2 &\neq 0
\end{align*}

I suppose that my inductive step is wrong but I'm not sure where I went wrong. Maybe I went wrong elsewhere. Any hints?

Comment: See also this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82140/show-that-f-0-f-1-f-2-cdots-f-2n-1-f-2n-f-2n-1-1-when-n

Comment: My question was a little more specific, don't you think? I knew it was induction, I just didn't know where I went wrong in my proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reasoning is sound, but your induction hypothesis is a bit wrong. It should be something like this:

---

Assume that it holds for $n = k$. We then have
$$
f_0 -f_1 + \cdots -f_{2k-1} +f_{2k} = f_{2k-1} -1
$$
I will now show that
$$
f_0 -f_1 + \cdots -f_{2k-1} +f_{2k} -f_{2k + 1} + f_{2k + 2} = f_{2k+1} -1
$$

---

If you solve that, then it will be proven.

Comment: Thank you. I was originally just adding 1 to the subscript instead of to the $n$. I also didn't realize that I needed to repeat both the $-f_{2k-1}$ and the $f_{2k}$ with the $+1$ to $k$. Your answer helped me find where I was going wrong!

Answer (score 3):

You get the inductive step by replacing $n$ everywhere with $n+1$. So the alternating sum should go up to $2(n+1)$, not $2n+1$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not notice this

Answer (score 2):

You have the inductive step wrong. What you want to prove is that
$$
f_0 - f_1 + f_2 - \dots - f_{2n+1} + f_{2n+2} = f_0 - f_1 + f_2 - \dots - f_{2(n+1)-1} + f_{2(n+1)} = f_{2(n+1)-1} - 1 = f_{2n+1} - 1.
$$
Perhaps it will be easier to prove something that's true. =D

Hope that helps,

Comment: It certainly helps when you try to prove something that's true x)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\ $ LHS,RHS both satisfy $\rm\ g(n+1) - g(n)\: =\: f_{2\:n},\ \ g(1) = 0\:.\:$ But it is both short and easy to *prove by induction* that the solutions $\rm\:g\:$  of this recurrence are *unique*. Therefore LHS = RHS.

Note that abstracting away from the specifics of the problem makes the proof both much more obvious and, additionally, yields a much more powerful result - one that applies to any functions satisfying a recurrence of this form. Generally [uniqueness theorems](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dubuque+uniqueness+theorem+proving) provide very powerful tools for proving equalities. For much further elaboration and many examples see my prior posts on [telescopy](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy) and the [fundamental theorem of difference calculus,](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com+dubuque+fundamental+theorem+%22difference+calculus%22) esp. [this one.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72668/242)