# Mathematical induction with the Fibonacci sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Let $F_n$ be the Fibonacci sequence:
$$
F_0 = 0,\ F_1 = 1 \\
F_n = F_{n−1} + F_{n−2}, n \geq 2
$$

Use mathematical induction to prove that for all positive integers $n$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \cdot F_i = (-1)^n \cdot F_{n-1} - 1$$

I understand the steps involving the base case, assuming the statement true for $n=k$ and then trying to prove that it's true for $n=k+1$. I am in the process of the actual induction and I'm trying to use the appropriate definitions to simplify my statement. It's not working out.

> $\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} (-1)^i(F_{i}) = (\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i(F_{i}))+(-1)^{k+1}*F_{k}-1$
>
> $(-1)^k(F_{k-1})+(-1)^{k+1}(F_{k})-1$
>
> $(-1)^k(F_{k-1})+(-1)(-1)^k(F_{k})-1$
>
> $(-1)^k(F_{k-1}-F_{k})-1$
>
> $(-1)^k(-1)(F_{k}-F_{k-1})-1$
>
> $(-1)^{k+1}(F_{k}-F_{k-1})-1$
>
> $(-1)^{k+1}(F_{k-2})-1$        (by the definition $F_{n}=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$)

I feel like I'm close to the pattern that I'm supposed to identify here, but the only part that doesn't match the original is the Fsub(k-2). It needs to be just Fsub(k), but I haven't been able to manipulate the algebra in a way that yields Fsub(k).

Comment: We use MathJax here. See [this help page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82140/show-that-f-0-f-1-f-2-cdots-f-2n-1-f-2n-f-2n-1-1-when-n

Comment: I think cocomarie823 is in the MAT 243 class that I teach. This is a problem that is due on tomorrow's homework assignment. ... And cocomarie823, your first line should end with $(-1)^{k+1} * F_{k+1}-1$, not $(-1)^{k+1} * F_{k}-1$

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate because this asks for all n, while that question asks for only even n.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it.

Assume that
$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i F_i 
= (-1)^n  F_{n-1} - 1
$.

You want to show that
$\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^i F_i 
= (-1)^{n+1}  F_{n} - 1
$.

Note that this
is just the assumption
with $n$ replaced by
$n+1$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} (-1)^i F_i 
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n} (-1)^i F_i+(-1)^{n+1}F_{n+1}
\qquad\text{(split off the last term)}\\
&=(-1)^n  F_{n-1} - 1+(-1)^{n+1}F_{n+1}
\qquad\text{(this was assumed)}\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}F_{n+1}+(-1)^n  F_{n-1} - 1\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}(F_{n+1}-  F_{n-1}) - 1\\
&=(-1)^{n+1}F_{n} - 1
\qquad\text{(since }F_{n+1}-  F_{n-1}=F_{n})\\
\end{array}
$

And we are done.

Comment: When I teach induction in my class, I tell the students to change the variable from $n$ to $k$. That way it doesn't look like you're assuming that the overall proposition is true during the induction part.

Comment: Good pedagogical point.

Answer (score 0):

Also, since $F_{k+1}=F_k+F_{k-1}$, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}(-1)^iF_i=(-1)^kF_{k-1}-1+(-1)^{k+1}F_{k}+(-1)^{k+1}F_{k-1}$. Since $k$ and $k+1$ are consecutive, one will be even and the other odd, so $(-1)^{k}+(-1)^{k+1}=0$, and the terms cancel.