# Write $F_{1}-F_{2}+F_{3}-F_{4}+...+F_{2n-1}-F_{2n}$ as a summation

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

Let $F_{i}$ be the $i^{th}$ Fibonacci number

(a) Write $F_{1}-F_{2}+F_{3}-F_{4}+...+F_{2n-1}-F_{2n}$ as a summation

(b) Prove $F_{1}-F_{2}+F_{3}-F_{4}+...+F_{2n-1}-F_{2n}=1-F_{2n-1}$

I'm quite confused. I've looked at how to express the Fibonacci sequence as a summation, as well as how to express just the odd or even numbers as a summation and based on that, this is my current understanding of the question.

(A) $\sum_{n=1}^{2n} f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{2n} (f(n)-f(n+1))$

(B) Hoping that I can add to this as we proceed along to part A?

Is that right or have I understood something wrong here?

Comment: Part (a) is only asking you for a change of notation $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k+1}F_{k}$.

Comment: Sorry, can you dissect what you wrote for me? I've been looking through it and I'm afraid I don't quite understand.

Comment: You can read about summations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). It is only a notation that allows you to write sums of many terms compactly, without having to write $...$, which can be ambiguous.

Comment: Part (b) can be done by [induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Description) on $n$. For $n=1$ the formula is $F_1-F_2=1-1=1-F_{2\cdot1-1}$. If you assume that the formula holds for $n=m$, then $\sum_{k=1}^{2n+2}(-1)^{k+1}F_k=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k+1}F_k+F_{2n+1}-F_{2n+2}=1-F_{2n-1}+(F_{2n+1}-F_{2n+2})=1-F_{2n-1}-F_{2n}=1-F_{2n+1}$.

Comment: Ok, part A makes sense to me now, thank you!

Comment: This is a very bad use of $n$: "$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2n} \,f(n)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2n} \,\big(f(n)-f(n+1)\big)$."  The variable $n$ is used as both an index and a fixed integer, rendering the expression meaningless.  Plus, if you were to write as a sum of differences, a correct expression would be $$\sum_{k=1}^n\,\big(F_{2k-1}-F_{2k}\big)\,.$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/82140/589

Answer (score 0):

For Part (b), note that
$$F_{2k-1}-F_{2k}=F_{2k-1}-\big(F_{2k-1}+F_{2k-2}\big)=-F_{2k-2}=F_{2k-3}-F_{2k-1}$$
for all $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ (noting that $F_{-1}=1$).